# Can't make this to work

Tags: java

I know any variable inside a switch have to be declared outside the scope of case statements, but I have tried to throw all calculations outside the Switch scope and still I am not getting the "total" result I want from this script. Can anyone help me please? I just want the last block commented statement in the very end of this script to work.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class script 
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    //initialization 
    Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in); 
    final double COST_WINE = 13.99; // What is the size of the bottle of wine? ***********************************
    final double COST_BEER_6 = 11.99, COST_BEER_12 = 19.99, COST_BEER_24 = 34.99;
    final double spirits_750 = 25.99, spirits_1000 = 32.99;
    final double gst = 0.05;  //confirm if this number is right***************************************************
    final double deposit750 = 0.10, deposit1000 = 0.25;

    double wineSubTotal, wineTotal , total_cost;
    double beer_6_SubTotal, beer_6_Total;
    double beer_12_SubTotal, beer_12_Total;
    double beer_24_SubTotal, beer_24_Total;
    double spirits_750_SubTotal, spirits_750_Total;
    double spirits_1000_SubTotal, spirits_1000_Total;
    int wineQuantity, beer_6_Quantity, beer_12_Quantity;
    int beer_24_Quantity, spirits_750_Quantity, spirits_1000_Quantity; 
    int beer_choice, spirits_choice; 
    char choice;
    String input, again;

    //loop for fun
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 40; i++)
    {
    System.out.print("-");
    }
    System.out.printf("\n*** Welcome to Yoshi's Liquor Mart ***\n");
    System.out.printf("Today's date is \n"); // Reserved for date***********************************************

    //another loop for fun                    
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 40; i++)
    {
    System.out.print("-");
    }

    //first actual loop, not for fun anymore

           do
           {
           System.out.printf("\nWine is $13.99" + "\nBeer 6 pack is $11.99\n" + "Beer 12 pack is $19.99\n" +
           "Beer 24 pack is $34.99\n" + "Spirits 750 mL is $25.99\n" + "Spirits 1000 mL is $32.99\n" + 
           "What is the item being purchased?\n" + "W for Wine, B for Beer and S for Spirits, or X to quit: "); 
           input = key.nextLine();
           choice = input.charAt(0);

               switch(choice)
               {
                 case('w'):
                 case('W'):
                      System.out.printf("\nHow many bottles of wine is being purchased? ");
                      wineQuantity = key.nextInt();
                      wineSubTotal = wineQuantity * COST_WINE;
                      wineTotal = (wineSubTotal * gst) + wineSubTotal + (deposit750 * wineQuantity);
                      System.out.printf("\nThe cost of " + wineQuantity + 
                      " bottles of wine including GST and deposit is %.2f\n", wineTotal);
                        break;
                 case('b'):
                 case('B'):
                      System.out.printf("What is size of the beer pack?\n" + "6, 12 or 24?");
                      beer_choice = key.nextInt();
                          if(beer_choice == 6)
                          {
                           System.out.printf("\nHow many 6 pack of beer is being purchased?");
                           beer_6_Quantity = key.nextInt(); 
                           beer_6_SubTotal = beer_6_Quantity * COST_BEER_6;
                           beer_6_Total = (beer_6_SubTotal * gst) + beer_6_SubTotal;
                           System.out.printf("\nThe cost of %d cases of 6 pack of beer" +
                           "including GST and deposit is %.2f\n", beer_6_Quantity, beer_6_Total); 
                          }
                          else if(beer_choice == 12)
                          {
                          System.out.printf("How many 12 pack of beer is being purchased?");
                          beer_12_Quantity = key.nextInt();
                          beer_12_SubTotal = beer_12_Quantity * COST_BEER_12;
                          beer_12_Total = (beer_12_SubTotal * gst) + beer_12_SubTotal;
                          System.out.printf("\nThe cost of %d cases of 12 pack of beer" +
                          "including GST and deposit is %.2f\n", beer_12_Quantity, beer_12_Total);                         
                          }  
                          else if(beer_choice == 24)
                          {
                          System.out.printf("How many 24 pack of beer is being purchased?");
                          beer_24_Quantity = key.nextInt();
                          beer_24_SubTotal = beer_24_Quantity * COST_BEER_24;
                          beer_24_Total = (beer_24_SubTotal * gst) + beer_24_SubTotal;
                          System.out.printf("\nThe cost of %d cases of 24 pack of beer" +
                          "including GST and deposit is %.2f\n", beer_24_Quantity, beer_24_Total);
                          }
                          else
                          {
                          System.out.println("Invalid number");
                          }  
                       break;
                 case('s'):
                 case('S'):
                      System.out.printf("What is size of Spirits?\n" + "750ml or 1000ml?");
                      spirits_choice = key.nextInt();
                          if(spirits_choice == 750)
                          {
                          System.out.printf("How many bottles are being purchased?");
                          spirits_750_Quantity = key.nextInt();
                          spirits_750_SubTotal = spirits_750_Quantity * spirits_750;
                          spirits_750_Total = (spirits_750_SubTotal * gst) + spirits_750_SubTotal + 
                          (deposit750 * spirits_750_Quantity);
                          System.out.printf("\nThe cost of %d bottle(s) of Spirits 750ml " +
                          "including GST and deposit is %.2f\n", spirits_750_Quantity, spirits_750_Total);                            
                          }
                          else if(spirits_choice == 1000)
                          {
                          System.out.printf("How many bottles are being purchased?");
                          spirits_1000_Quantity = key.nextInt();
                          spirits_1000_SubTotal = spirits_1000_Quantity * spirits_1000;
                          spirits_1000_Total = (spirits_1000_SubTotal * gst) + spirits_1000_SubTotal + 
                          (deposit1000 * spirits_1000_Quantity);
                          System.out.printf("\nThe cost of %d bottle(s) of Spirits 1000ml " +
                          "including GST and deposit is %.2f\n", spirits_1000_Quantity, spirits_1000_Total);                            
                          }
                          else
                          {
                          System.out.println("Invalid number");
                          }  
                        break;
                  case('x'):     
                  case('X'):

                        break;
                  default:
                          System.out.printf("Invalid choice");
                        break;

               }

          System.out.println("Is this customer's order complete? ");
          again = key.nextLine();
          }
          while(again.equals("n"));


         //Total cost

         /*total_cost = wineTotal + beer_6_Total + beer_12_Total + beer_24_Total + 
         spirits_750_Total + spirits_1000_Total;

         System.out.printf("The total cost for this customer is %f", total_cost);*/

   key.close(); //There was a warning message(not error), so I found out on StackOverFlow that this would close the Scanner
  }

}
```

Comment: The code you have pasted is very long and surely contains much that is correct. You will get better answers if you create, from scratch,  a minimal file that still shows the problem. Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Cnunes Can you tell input and expected output??

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use, say, `wineTotal` after the loop (as your commented-out code seems to suggest), you should initialize it to 0 in the declaration so that it also has a value in case no wine is being bought.

If you prefer to declare local variables in each `case` of your `switch` statement (like I often do), just have them inside `{` and `}`:

```
        case ('w'):
        case ('W'): {
            System.out.printf("\nHow many bottles of wine is being purchased? ");
            int wineQuantity = key.nextInt();
            double wineSubTotal = wineQuantity * COST_WINE;
            wineTotal = (wineSubTotal * gst) + wineSubTotal + (deposit750 * wineQuantity);
            System.out.printf(
                    "\nThe cost of " + wineQuantity + " bottles of wine including GST and deposit is %.2f\n",
                    wineTotal);
        }
            break;
```

Your program runs fine the first time through the loop. Even when I answer `n` to `Is this customer's order complete?`, the program terminates. I think this is because after reading a number of bottles with `key.nextInt()`, the program still hasn’t read the newline after the number. So when asking whether the order is complete and reading an answer with `key.nextLine()`, the program takes the remainder of the line with the quantity, usually an empty string, which isn’t equal to `"n"`, so it exits the do loop.

For your next question os Stack Overflow (if you will have one), James K’s suggestion is still a good one: produce a minimal, complete and verifiable example before posting.